# Call a google cloud function from C# desktop app?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-functions

I have some sensitive information inside my code
[image]
i want to create a cloud function that return me the sensitive information. Is there are any way to call cloud function and receive the data from C# desktop app?

Comment: What do you mean by "receive the data"? And where does Firebase fit into this? You can create Google Cloud Functions triggered by HTTP requests and trigger those from any app... but it's not clear to me whether that would help you. If you could put a lot more context in your question, it would really help.

Comment: I read your question multiple times but it does not make sense (to me). Please clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish and use an example if possible. Securing information can really mean anything.

Comment: I think I understand. You have settings or configuration keys you do not want hard coded in your application and would prefer to retrieve them from an API end point at runtime? Is that accurate? If so you would need to create some API end point as well as a means of authenticating and authorizing to that end point to return the settings but yes that is a valid use case and possible. Another option is to create a deployment configuration that is included when you deploy the app to the end user.

Comment: Τhere is a code or docs or some source that doing those things ?

Comment: You need to be authenticated to get these sensitive data. Can you achieve that? Do you know your users?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yeah i have them all in Authentication but i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call an authenticated Cloud Function(CF) from a c# desktop application, this is what you need to do.

1. [Create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) a custom Google service account.
2. [Create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) a key json file from the previous service account.
   At the end of the process, you should have a key json file that will be used by the dotnet application to authenticate with  the Cloud Function.
3. Deploy a Cloud Function that will handle the sensitive data. For a proof of concept test I have used the [Cloud Functions quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstarts) that returns the message "hello world".
4. Enforce authentication in the Cloud Function.
   For this, you need to go to the [Cloud Functions main page](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list) and tick the checkbox at the left of the CF name.
   Then at the top of the screen, you need to click on the option **Permissions**(a right panel will be shown).
   From the role/member list, expand the section **Cloud Function invoker**.
   Remove the identity `AllUsers` since this makes the CF public and only add the name of the service account created.
5. Create a dotnet local web application
   `dotnet new web -o helloworld --no-https`
6. Install the [Google Auth library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/) to generate identity tokens.
   `dotnet add package Google.Apis.Auth --version 1.53.0`
7. Include the following pieces of code in Startup.cs to call the authenticated Cloud Function.

```
endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
    Console.WriteLine("Program starting");    
    //Creating identity token from service account key json file of step 2
    //The key json file is located in the same folder that the Startup.cs
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("[FILENAME].json");
    var audience= "[CLOUD_FUNCTION_URL]";
    var token = await credential.GetOidcTokenAsync(OidcTokenOptions.FromTargetAudience(audience), CancellationToken.None);
    String bt = await token.GetAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    //Create http client to send web request
    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",bt);
    HttpResponseMessage hr = await hc.GetAsync("[CLOUD_FUNCTION_URL]");
    string responseBody = await hr.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Program completed");
});
```

8. These are the libraries I needed to import at the top of the Startup.cs file.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
```

9. Finally execute `dotnet watch run` and see that the message from the authenticated Cloud Function(hello world) is printed on the local console.

I hope you find this useful